# NSString fails as a parameter, but literal string works?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I'm pulling an array of song names from my AWS server.

My next step is to use one of those song names as a parameter in a request to retrieve the its streamable URL.

```
    //[1] Initialize the S3 Client.
    self.s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"blah" withSecretKey:@"blah"];
    self.s3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_WEST_2];



    //[2] Get an array of song names
    NSArray *song_array = [self.s3 listObjectsInBucket:@"blahblah"];
    NSLog(@"the objects are %@", song_array);


    //[3] Get a single song name from the array
    NSString *song1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
    song1 = (NSString *)[song_array objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@", song1);

    NSString * song2 =  @"Rap God.mp3";
    NSLog(@"%@", song2);


    //[4] Get the Song URL
    S3GetPreSignedURLRequest *gpsur = [[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init];
    gpsur.key                     = song2;
    gpsur.bucket                  =@"soundshark";
    gpsur.expires                 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval) 3600]; 
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *url = [self.s3 getPreSignedURL:gpsur error:&error];
    NSLog(@"the url is %@", url);
```

Song2 works perfectly as the parameter gpsur.key.

However, if I use song1 as a parameter, it fails with the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[S3ObjectSummary stringWithURLEncoding]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175aef30

When I use NSLog, both song1 and song2 print the exact same string "Rap God.mp3"

Why the error? Why can't I just use the string from the array? It has the exact same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
NSString *song1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
song1 = (NSString *)[song_array objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@", song1);
```

to

```
S3ObjectSummary *s3object = [song_array objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *song1 = [s3object description];
NSLog(@"%@", song1);
```

If it will work it will be better to change

```
NSString *song1 = [s3object description];
```

to

```
NSString *song1 = [s3object etag];
```

or

```
NSString *song1 = [s3object key];
```

I am not familiar with S3ObjectSummary so I can not suggest what variant is better.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that "song1" is not actually an NSString. The following means that you're trying to call a method on an object of class S3SObjectSummary that doesn't exist. This tells you that "song1" is an S3SObjectSummary instead of an NSString.

```
'-[S3ObjectSummary stringWithURLEncoding]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

To fix this issue I found the documentation for S3ObjectSummary which describes how to get the NSString value from this object with the property "description". [S3ObjectSummary description]

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/S3ObjectSummary.html#//api/name/description

So in your case the NSString would be `song1.description`

To put this all together you get the following.

```
//Grab the S3ObjectSummary from the array
    S3ObjectSummary *song1 = (S3ObjectSummary*)[song_array objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@", song1);

// Use the description property of S3ObjectSummary to get the string value.
    NSString *stringFromObjectSummary = song1.description;


    S3GetPreSignedURLRequest *gpsur = [[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init];
    gpsur.key                     = stringFromObjectSummary;
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight you should use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` to encode unallowed character in url:

Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for encoding purpose.

Also, you should try like this to construct a string from array element.

```
NSString *song1 = [NString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [song_array objectAtIndex:1]];
NSLog(@"%@", song1);
```